# Full screen resolution issues with games in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, resolution

I updated my mom's computer to Windows 10 from Windows 7.  She is now complaining about the games not working properly which means the games don't run in full screen properly - they bottom quarter is off screen. I have an issue with Windows 10 not being able to run at the monitors full screen native resolution (1920x1080), but it has to run at a lower resolution (1600x900) to be at all usable or show all the screen elements.

I've been looking around for options. I can run the game in windowed mode, but she wants it back to how it used to be, using "all the screen".  I don't want to rollback to Windows 7.

It's a basic Intel onboard CPU GPU desktop computer with no DVI output. I'm sure it's got to do with the analog output, but as she rightly says, it used to work fine before with the same hardware.

How do I make my mom happy and get full screen games to play properly?

Comment: I actually think the screen somehow lost its ability to go fullscreen on some level after upgrading to win10. No idea that is possible. But compatibility is getting better as time goes on.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10 a lot of games weren't running correctly in full screen, and windowed mode wasn't full screen either. I spent quite some time finding this, but there is another solution

Basically, use an app called [ShiftWindow](http://grismar.net/shiftwindow/) to make the game run in full screen, but as a window instead of as true full screen.
This works great on my mom's computer and she is happy and can play her games as she was used to on Windows 7.

I had to train her how to use the app, but it was a once off and she manages it fine on her own now.